# Installation directory in CMakeLists.txt, suitable for Visual Studio and Qt Creator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, qt-creator

I have to deal with CMake 3.x, Qt Creator 3.3.0, Qt 4.8.6, Visual Studio 2008 in Windows (and rarely Qt Creator + GCC in Debian).

This instruction

> install(TARGETS ${PROJECT} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib)

is not comfortable because of mixing debug and release `*.lib` files in the same directory. I'd like to save `libs` in the corresponding subfolder.

I've tried the following instruction from [here](http://cmake.limitpoint.com/installing-multiple-build-types-in-cmake-generated-visual-studio-projects-2/):

> install(TARGETS ${PROJECT} DESTINATION
>   ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/\${BUILD_TYPE})

It works fine for Visual Studio, as it is a multi-configuration solution and we pass `${BUILD_TYPE}`, protected by backslash `'\'` for further propagation.
But how can I achieve the same output for `Qt Creator + MS C++ compiler`? Should I assign `Debug`(for example) to `${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}` (via command-line interface) and special custom flag, which tells CMake that we deal with nmake/make? I mean conditional install instruction which will work fine in Windows and Linux and require minimal differences in the command-line arguments for `CMake`. I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is a standard solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You saw that you can use `BUILD_TYPE` variable **set at compile time** to configure the target folder of your library at installation. This is specific to Visual Studio.

In other build systems (make, nmake, ninja, etc.) you have to use `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable, **set at configuration time** to retrieve the same information. In such case, as you felt, different configurations (Debug and Release) have to be generated in separated build folders. In these folders, CMake generation step is done with the right value in `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable. Example:

```
cd /home/user/project/xx_project/build_release
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release /home/user/project/xx_project/src
cd /home/user/project/xx_project/build_debug
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug /home/user/project/xx_project/src
```

To detect if the user is building from Visual Studio or from command line, "there is a variable for that": [The MSVC_IDE Cmake variable](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/MSVC_IDE.html)

A solution can be something like

```
if(MSVC_IDE)
  install(TARGETS ${PROJECT} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/\${BUILD_TYPE})
else()
  install(TARGETS ${PROJECT} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})
endif()
```

I am not completely sure of the necessity of the backslash before ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}. You should test that by yourself